# Get location permission in React Native for IOS

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, react-native

Can't get the location permissions. I gave the app all the permissions needed for the API. Here is link to my code: https://github.com/romanbr87/MyJS/blob/58686cd847c725362d3649ce141d5e26d6775a7f/Header.js

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The code is in the link

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have added the following lines in your info.plist file

You can find it in: your project main file >> ios >> <your_project_name> >> info.plist

```
<dict>
...
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string></string>
</dict>
```